# Java Time anomaly

Tags: java, oracle, datetime

I am using this code to set an old date and store it in Database, but when I retrieve it from the Database the value is changed from what I have stored. could you please point me to the correct direction for debugging.

```
new Timestamp(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy").parse("31-DEC-79").getTime())
```

The value I see in the Database is 1981-07-12 00:00:00.0   why is there a difference?

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure you're looking at the right column/row in the database

Comment: Yes there is only one column in my Database Table with timestamp. Do i need to set any time zones or such?

Comment: Could you post the code you're using to store this value in database and retrieve it afterwards?

Comment: How are you updating the database? PreparedStatement etc? Can you post the code as well? I doubt timezone will cause a 2 year difference.

Comment: Basically I populate my domain object and my service method has a call for hibernate session's saveOrUpdate method.

Comment: Don't close the question - it is valid. See my answer for why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry About the confusion, i switched the date with month when parsing it. it is working and storing as it should.

Answer (score 2):

This may give a clue:

```
    new Timestamp(new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yy").parse("31-12-79").getTime());
    // 1981-07-12 00:00:00.0
```

1981-07-12 is day 12 of month 31 of year 79 (I know - there's no month 31, but java will parse it like that anyway)

Either your dates/code are not as posted, or you are parsing your dates correctly, but your database is expecting dates in the american format (MM-dd-yy) and you are sending it dates in the european format (dd-MM-yy) - the days/months are being swapped.